# How do I setup my Element Types Sources for deep linking?

Tags: routes, elementtype, routing, sources

In the Entries tab in the Control Panel, I see a list of Sources on the left hand side:

- All Entries
- Singles
- News

When I click on each of these sources the page filters the appropriate results in the body and the URL gets updated appropriately:

- All Entries => `/admin/entries`
- Singles => `/admin/entries/singles`
- News => `/admin/entries/news`

This is nice as I can now send links to other people to a specific sub-section in the sources, with the contents already filtered.

I've compared my code in the source `nav` to the code on the Entries Element Index page, and they are comparable, including passing the `data-handle` value to each source. But it's still not working in my Custom Element type. I must be missing something but I haven't yet figured out what.

How do we get this behavior working for custom Element Types?

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin has to create those routes — via [`registerCpRoutes()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/hooks-reference#registerCpRoutes) — to match your desired URL structure.

Routes either trigger a site template or a controller, as described in the [Routing](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing) docs. *(Craft's own internal convention is for CP routes to trigger a controller method, which sets up the request and renders your desired template.)*

You can look at Craft's own CP routes for inspiration in setting up your own; they're defined in `/app/etc/config/common.php`.